# RecyclerView does not show the desired card at the expected postion?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

So I am trying to create a gridlayout with recyclerview with each grid representing a cardview. I am testing it by trying to load number images like 0,1,2.... in the expected positions. But the numbers just keep jumping around in wired places sometimes repeating themselves. I am guessing this is an adapter problem. Could you look at my code and tell me where I am wrong.

```
public class GridAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GridAdapter.ViewHolder>  {
private Context context;
String[] numbers;
public GridAdapter(Context context){
    super();
    this.context=context;

}
@Override
public GridAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.grid, viewGroup, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(GridAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    String[] numbers={//contains url's for number images strating from 0};
    Picasso.with(context).load(numbers[i]).into(ViewHolder.imageView);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return return numbers.length;
}


static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public static ImageView imageView;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    }
}
}
```

And by the way number array is populated by an asynctask in the main activity and recyclerview and layoutmanager are set in onCreate and adapter is set in onPostExecute of the asynctask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ViewHolder` doesn't work properly. The reference to `ImageView` shouldn't be `static` because you will have multiple `ViewHolders` for list and you won't be able to store references this way.

Fix your `ViewHolder` and it will work properly.

See an example here: https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html